# How to swipe pivot when Listbox is empty

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, pivot, swipe, populate

I have a pivot page which have 3 pivot items. In the default pivot item is a `ListBox`.

I use `ObservableCollection` to populate this `ListBox`. When `ListBox` is populated, I can swipe the pivot.

However, when `ObservableCollection` has no item, which means `ListBox` is not populated, I cannot swipe pivot anymore

Someone asked exactly the same on [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/8367feb2-c479-4374-8ef2-df9625a30285)

How to fix this ?

Comment: Can you post the xaml for your pivot ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu My xaml is very similar to the one asked on msdn, please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code from [msdn question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/8367feb2-c479-4374-8ef2-df9625a30285) it looks like the Pivot is resized due to the VerticalAlignment value:

```
 <controls:Pivot Title="UTORRENT REMOTE" 
                 SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" 
                 Height="696" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

To get the behavior that you want remove the VerticalAlignment from the pivot:

```
 <controls:Pivot Title="UTORRENT REMOTE" 
                 SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" 
                 Height="696">
```

Comment: It works for me. But what I don't understand is that my pivot has Height="*", so how can VerticalAlignment affect ?

Comment: I'm not sure, as far as I know if you use Height="*" on your pivot control you should get a runtime exception.